# React-admin turning off reliance on X-Total-Count

Tags: django, reactjs, react-admin

I expected React-admin to work out the box with Django Rest Framework, like its website implied but my experience is that it doesn't. It has been a time consuming task trying to set custom headers to fit react-admins requirement for X-Total-Count header for every response. Django Rest Framework prefers to put the count in to the json response it seems.

Does anyone know how to read this information from the json instead? It seems logical to me to set an option in react admin instead of rewriting the middleware with Django or other rest frameworks.

Comment: It's pretty straightforward with a custom data provider (which you'll probably end up needing anyway). In the meantime, you could wrap the provider you are currently using with a [decorator](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#decorating-your-data-provider-example-of-file-upload) that just copies the count from the response to the returned `total`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution example using Class based Views.

example of views.py:

```
from .models import AzureADList
from rest_framework import pagination
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import AzureADListSerializer
from rest_framework import generics


def _positive_int(integer_string, strict=False, cutoff=None):
    """
    Cast a string to a strictly positive integer.
    """
    ret = int(integer_string)
    if ret < 0 or (ret == 0 and strict):
        raise ValueError()
    if cutoff:
        return min(ret, cutoff)
    return ret

class StandardResultsSetPagination(pagination.LimitOffsetPagination):
    '''This is to handle react-admins call to our API when paginating'''
    offset_query_param = '_start'

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        headers={'X-Total-Count': self.count}
        response = Response(data, headers=headers)
        return response

    def get_limit(self, request):

        print('request query params..')
        print(request.query_params)
        try:
            end = request.query_params['_end']
            start = request.query_params['_start']
            limit = int(end) - int(start)
            return _positive_int(limit)

        except (KeyError, ValueError):
            pass

        return self.default_limit

class UserViewSet(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = AzureADList.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AzureADListSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        response = self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        return response
```